# Fourier transform of $x^2(1+x^2)^{-2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have the following

$$
\mathscr{F} \{ x^2 (1+x^2)^{-2} \} ( \xi )
$$

All I could think of was

$$
-\frac{d^2}{d\xi ^2} \mathscr{F} \{ (1+x^2)^{-2} \}(\xi)
$$

but I don't know what to do next. I could solve this if the power of the expression was only $-1$.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate integrals using the residue theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Yes. It is detailed in this response http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377073/calculate-the-fourier-transform-of-bx-frac1x2-a2

Comment: BTW, one of the answers to that question shows how to do it using the residue theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathscr F\left\{ x^2 (1+x^2)^{-2} \right\} ( \xi )&=\mathrm i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\xi}\mathscr F\left\{ x(1+x^2)^{-2} \right\} ( \xi )\\&=\frac12\mathrm i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\xi}\mathscr F\left\{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(1+x^2)^{-1} \right\} ( \xi )\\&=\frac12\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\xi}\xi\mathscr F\left\{(1+x^2)^{-1} \right\} ( \xi )\;.
\end{align}

Comment: A thousand thanks, friend :) Will mark answer when its possible