# I wan't clearly justifying the $C^1$-ness of $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2}\, dt $ in terms of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Using domination theorem for $C^1$ parameters integrals we have to show that :

$|\sin(xt)*x/(1+x^2)|$ is integrable in terms of $x.$ But majorations are not trivial (here it gives a useless divergent majoration).

Evaluate $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{1+t^2}\, dt $$ as $\pi/e$ is rather easy when when don't care about the $C^1$ theorem.

Have you a correct, complete solution including rigorous proofs?

If a detailed post already exists, feel free to show me the path.

Comment: Use $|\cos|, |\sin|\le 1$.

Comment: Thank you but  it isn't the problem there : we want to proove integrability our sin expression but $ x/x^2+1$ integral diverges

Comment: OK, i will write the answer, too few space here. Idea: Let $f(x)$ be the function defined by the integral, it is a function of the parameter $x$, for our purposes, $-2018\le x\le 2018$. Directly computing $f'(x)$ by exchanging differentiation with integration does not work, but we can use first partial integration to get a better denominator. By differentiation we get then a valid differential equation, then we solve it. Note: The exchange of the rôles of $x$ and $t$ in the title and in the text is really irritating. (At least, your problem becomes unclear.)

Comment: Will try partial integration before , its ok for the following steps

Comment: I expected to get easily the result, since the integral is related to the Fourier transform of the function $g(t)=1/(1+t^2)$. If this is OK, then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377073/calculate-the-fourier-transform-of-bx-frac1x2-a2 is the answer.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to reach the result by a more classical way (so I need clear arguments for it ) , without using Fourier Bazooka or Green Theorem .

Comment: Integration by parts is perfect on our sin expression , applying C1 theorems on the second integrals

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution uses complex analysis, residue theorem.
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &=
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\text{Real part of }
\frac 12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp(itx)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\text{Real part of }
\frac 12\lim_{R\to\infty}
\int_{-R}^R\frac{\exp(itx)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\text{Real part of }
\frac 12\lim_{R\to\infty}
\int_\gamma\frac{\exp(itx)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&\qquad\text{where $\gamma$ is the closed contour built from }
\\
&\qquad\text{the segment $[-R,R]$, followed by the upper semicircle 
on this diameter,}
\\
&=
\text{Real part of }
\frac 12\cdot 2\pi i\cdot 
\text{Residue}_{t=i}\frac{\exp(itx)}{(t+i)(t-i)}
\\
&=
\text{Real part of }
\frac 12\cdot 2\pi i\cdot 
\frac{\exp(-x)}{i+i}
\\
&=
\frac\pi 2\exp(-x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
To be complete, we have to give an upper bound on the
integral on the upper semicircle with radius $R$, parametrized by 
$s\to Re^{is}$. Note thet we integrate a function which is bounded in module by $1/(R^2-1)$, taken at most times the length of the semicircle, $\pi R$. This product converges to zero for $R\to\infty$.

This argument extends easily to similar integrals.

---

If complex analysis is still considered to be heavy metal, or if 
we need an alternative solution supporting the ideas from the post, then here is a way to proceed.

For short, leg $g$ be the rational function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$,
$$g(t)=\frac 1{t^2+1}\ .$$
Its first derivatives can be easily computed with mathematical software aid, so this is not our point. The derivatives of order $0,1,2,3,\dots$ get a better and better total degree in $t$, for performing derivation "inside the integral", namely $-2,-3,-4,-5,\dots$ so we can write: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)
&=
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\cos(tx)\cdot g(t)\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1x\sin(tx)\cdot g'(t)\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
-\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)\cdot g''(t)\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
-\frac 1{x^3}\sin(tx)\cdot g'''(t)\; dt
\\
\\
&=\dots
\\
&\qquad\text{ an so on, and if we want we can further improve the polynomial growth at $t=\infty$.}
\\
&\qquad\text{ Then}
\\
\\
f'(x)
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
-\frac 1{x^3}\sin(tx)\cdot g'''(t)\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
-
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\left(\ \frac 1{x^3}\sin(tx)\ \right)\cdot g'''(t)\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
-
\left(\ \frac {(-3)}x\cdot\frac 1{x^3}\sin(tx)
+\frac 1{x^3}\cos(tx)\cdot t
\ \right)\cdot g'''(t)\; dt
\\
&=
-\frac 3xf(x)
+
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
-
\frac 1{x^3}\cos(tx)\cdot t\cdot g'''(t)\; dt
\\
&=
-\frac 3xf(x)
-
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^3}\cos(tx)\cdot \left(\ \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\ \right)'\; dt
\\
&=
-\frac 3xf(x)
+
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\sin(tx)\cdot \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&
\\
f''(x)
&=
\frac 3{x^2}f(x)
-
\frac 3x f'(x)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac\partial{\partial x}
\left(\ \frac 1{x^2}\sin(tx)\ \right)
\cdot \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 3{x^2}f(x)
-
\frac 3x f'(x)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac{(-2)}x
\cdot \frac 1{x^2}\sin(tx)
\cdot \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\cdot t\cdot \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 3{x^2}f(x)
-
\frac 3x \left(\ 
-\frac 3xf(x)
+
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\sin(tx)\cdot \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\ \right)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac{(-2)}x
\cdot \frac 1{x^2}\sin(tx)
\cdot \frac {8t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\cdot \frac {8t^4}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac {12}{x^2}f(x)
-
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^3}\sin(tx)\cdot \frac {8(2+3)t^3}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\cdot \frac {8t^4}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac {12}{x^2}f(x)
+
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^3}\sin(tx)\cdot
\left(\ \frac {10(2t^2+1)}{(t^2+1)^2}\ \right)'\; dt
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\cdot \frac {8t^4}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac {12}{x^2}f(x)
+
\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)\cdot\frac {10(2t^2+1)}{(t^2+1)^2}\; dt
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\cdot \frac {8t^4}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\left[\
\frac {12}{t^2+1}
-
\frac {10(2t^2+1)}{(t^2+1)^2}
+
\frac {8t^4}{(t^2+1)^3}
\ \right]\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
-\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)
\frac {2(3t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
-\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)\cdot
\frac {2(3t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_{\Bbb R}
-\frac 1{x^2}\cos(tx)\cdot g''(t)\; dt
\\
&=f(x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
From $f''(x)=f(x)$ we can finally fix the formula for $f$. The value for $f(0)$ is $\pi/2$. For the derivative $f'(0)$ we have to work a little 
more... (I was curious to see if it is possible to avoid "higher stuff", and give a proof using the lines inspired by the post.)

Answer (score 0):

For $x >0$, we have
$$f(x) = x \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2 + t^2} dt,$$
which easily implies that $f$ is $C^1$ for $x >0$.Function $f$ is even, hence it is $C^1$ for any $x\not=0$, and
$$f'(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2 +t^2} dt - 2x^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos t}{(x^2 + t^2)^2} dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2 -x^2)\cos t}{(t^2 +x^2)^2}dt.$$

Since $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2 -x^2}{(t^2 +x^2)^2} dt =0$, hence
$$f'(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2 -x^2)(\cos t -1)}{(t^2 +x^2)^2}dt = -2\int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2 -x^2)(\sin \frac t2)^2}{(t^2 +x^2)^2}dt.$$
Note that
$$\left|\frac{(t^2 -x^2)(\sin \frac t2)^2}{(t^2 +x^2)^2}\right| \leq \frac{(\sin \frac t2)^2}{t^2} \in L^1(0,\infty).$$
By dominated convergence theorem, we have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = -2 \int_0^\infty \frac{(\sin \frac t2)^2}{t^2} dt.  \qquad (*)$$
We compute $f'(0)$. For $x >0$, we have $f(0) = \int_0^\infty (1 +t^2)^{-1} dt = x \int_0^\infty (x^2 + t^2)^{-1} dt$. Therefore
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = -2\int_0^\infty \frac{(\sin \frac t2)^2}{x^2 + t^2} dt.$$
Again by dominated convergence theorem, we get
$$f'(0) =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) -f(0)}{x} = -2 \int_0^\infty \frac{(\sin \frac t2)^2}{t^2} dt.   \qquad (**)$$
From (*) and (**), we get $f$ is $C^1$ at $x =0$.